# Turkish currency in Excel Apache Poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to set Turkish currency to my document(or cells) with

```
cellStyle.setDataFormat(ExcelStyleBuilder.getInstance().getPriceDataFormat().getFormat("₺#,#0.00"));
```

but after that Numbers(MacOS excel application) does not recognize the format. When i create a excel file and set price it gets Turkish currency by default.

I checked some examples for Indian currency and it fails on my computer as well. Is there any way to set whole excel workbook to default currency or do i have to change currency after creating it.

```
//this works and displays USD currency.
cellStyle.setDataFormat(ExcelStyleBuilder.getInstance().getPriceDataFormat().getFormat("$#,#0.00")); //this works and displays USD currency.

cellStyle.setDataFormat((short)8); // this works and displays USD currency.
```

Comment: What is `ExcelStyleBuilder`? What does `getPriceDataFormat()` return? What does `getFormat("₺#,#0.00")` return? Why not using [DataFormat](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormat.html) as shown in https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DataFormats? What means "does not recognize the format"? What is displayed by MacOS Numbers?

Comment: getPriceDataFormat returns DataFormat. Numbers display format does not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Using this one can check what works and what works not. This also may be helpful for other possible helpers which are able testing using `MacOS` `Numbers`.

The following code creates a `CreateExcelDifferentCurrencyStyles.xlsx` file in `Office Open XML` format. This contains and uses following cell styles:

`defaultCurrency` = uses the default currency format of `Excel`.

`defaultUSDCurrency` = uses `en-US` currency format given by `$` sign in combination with [Windows Language Code Identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/70feba9f-294e-491e-b6eb-56532684c37f) `409` for `en-US`.

`defaultTurkishCurrency` = uses `tr-TR` currency format given by lira sign in comnbination with [Windows Language Code Identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/70feba9f-294e-491e-b6eb-56532684c37f) `41F` for `tr-TR`. The literal "\u20BA" instead of lira sign is used for being independent of encoding of `*.java` code file.

`customTurkishCurrency1` = uses a custom format with lira sign immediatelly before number format codes.

`customTurkishCurrency2` = uses a custom format with lira sign preceded by backslash,  followed by number format codes. Putting a backslash before a sign is one possibility to escape possible special meaning of that sign in number format code.

`customTurkishCurrency3` = uses a custom format with lira sign surrounded by quotes,  followed by number format codes. Surrounding a sign by quotes is another possibility to escape possible special meaning of that sign in number format code.

`yourCustomTurkishCurrency` = uses your given custom format.

Complete code example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelDifferentCurrencyStyles {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  DataFormat dataformat = workbook.createDataFormat();

  CellStyle defaultCurrency = workbook.createCellStyle();
  defaultCurrency.setDataFormat((short)8); //see https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html
  CellStyle defaultUSDCurrency = workbook.createCellStyle();
  defaultUSDCurrency.setDataFormat(dataformat.getFormat("[$$-409]#,##0.00"));
  CellStyle defaultTurkishCurrency = workbook.createCellStyle();
  defaultTurkishCurrency.setDataFormat(dataformat.getFormat("[$" + "\u20BA" + "-41F]#,##0.00"));

  CellStyle customTurkishCurrency1 = workbook.createCellStyle();
  customTurkishCurrency1.setDataFormat(dataformat.getFormat("\u20BA" + "#,##0.00"));
  CellStyle customTurkishCurrency2 = workbook.createCellStyle();
  customTurkishCurrency2.setDataFormat(dataformat.getFormat("\\" + "\u20BA" + "#,##0.00"));
  CellStyle customTurkishCurrency3 = workbook.createCellStyle();
  customTurkishCurrency3.setDataFormat(dataformat.getFormat("\"" + "\u20BA" + "\"" + "#,##0.00"));

  CellStyle yourCustomTurkishCurrency = workbook.createCellStyle();
  yourCustomTurkishCurrency.setDataFormat(dataformat.getFormat("\u20BA" + "#,#0.00"));

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");

  double value = 12345678.9;
  Cell cell;
  int r = 0;
  sheet.createRow(r).createCell(0).setCellValue("defaultCurrency");
  cell = sheet.getRow(r++).createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue(value);
  cell.setCellStyle(defaultCurrency);

  sheet.createRow(r).createCell(0).setCellValue("defaultUSDCurrency");
  cell = sheet.getRow(r++).createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue(value);
  cell.setCellStyle(defaultUSDCurrency);

  sheet.createRow(r).createCell(0).setCellValue("defaultTurkishCurrency");
  cell = sheet.getRow(r++).createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue(value);
  cell.setCellStyle(defaultTurkishCurrency);

  sheet.createRow(r).createCell(0).setCellValue("customTurkishCurrency1");
  cell = sheet.getRow(r++).createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue(value);
  cell.setCellStyle(customTurkishCurrency1);

  sheet.createRow(r).createCell(0).setCellValue("customTurkishCurrency2");
  cell = sheet.getRow(r++).createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue(value);
  cell.setCellStyle(customTurkishCurrency2);

  sheet.createRow(r).createCell(0).setCellValue("customTurkishCurrency3");
  cell = sheet.getRow(r++).createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue(value);
  cell.setCellStyle(customTurkishCurrency3);

  sheet.createRow(r).createCell(0).setCellValue("yourCustomTurkishCurrency");
  cell = sheet.getRow(r++).createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue(value);
  cell.setCellStyle(yourCustomTurkishCurrency);

  sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
  sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateExcelDifferentCurrencyStyles.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  workbook.close();
  out.close();

 }
}
```

All those number formats work as expected when the `CreateExcelDifferentCurrencyStyles.xlsx` is opened by `Excel`, `LibreOffice Calc` or `Google Sheets`.

Please check whether some of those number formats are recognized by `Numbers` too.

I've checked using `ICloud Numbers`. The result looks like so:

[image]

So format `[$₺-41F]#,##0.00` is displayed as 12.345.678,90 TRY. And formats using unmasked lira sign in number format codes do not work.

But both variants using masked lira signs work. That are `\₺#,##0.00` as well as `"₺"#,##0.00`.

Comment: Thank you mate for your help. "\\" + "\u20BA" + "#,##0.00". This worked